# How to add DELETE operation to a button Node.js

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs, crud

I want to add a delete functionality to a button that's part of a card which is encapsulated in a form this is as far I got:

```
<form class="form-events" action="/delete" method="post">
  <% events.forEach( function (event) { %>
    
      <div class="card col-lg-3" style="width: 18rem;">

          <img class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><%= event.title %></h5>
          <p class="card-text"><%= event.description %></p>
          <p class="card-text"><%= event.date %> </p>
          <p class="card-text"><%= event.capacity %></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
          <button onclick="this.form.submit()" value="<%= event._id %> " name="deletebtn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
   
  <% }); %>
</form>
```

And this is the route for it:

```
// Delete an event
app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
  const deletedItemId = req.body.deletebtn;
  Event.findByIdAndRemove(deletedItemId, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Successfully deleted");
      res.redirect("/admin");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

I get this error when I press the delete button:

```
     reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex 
                   characters
```

[image: Full Console Error Message]

Comment: First off, I would recommend using `collection.findOneByIdAndDelete()`. Second, the error is pretty clear that `event._id` is not of the correct type. Can you include the console ouput of what `event._id` looks like when you pass it into the request. Also, are you using Mongoose to define a schema or just Node.js for defining the endpoints?

Comment: When you debug, does the page source have the expected ID value?  In the POST request in your browser's debugging tools, does it include the expected ID value?  Debugging the server-side code, does `deletedItemId` have the value you expect?  It's important to observe each individual step of the logic in debugging to determine where specifically something unexpected is happening.

Comment: I added a message from the console, as far as for the debugging I am pretty new to this so don't know how tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is how I solved I am not sure if it's the correct way, but it works.

**Form admin.ejs**

```
<% events.forEach( function (event) { %>
      <form class="form-events" action="/delete" method="post">

        <div class="card col-lg-3" style="width: 18rem;">

          <img class="card-img-top">
          <div class="card-body">

            <h5 class="card-title"><%= event.title %></h5>
            <p class="card-text"><%= event.description %></p>
            <p class="card-text"><%= event.date %> </p>
            <p class="card-text"><%= event.capacity %></p>

            <a href="/create_event" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
            <button name="deleteBtn" value="<%=event._id%>" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <% }); %>
      </form>
```

**The app.js for the route**

```
app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {

  const deletedItemId = req.body.deleteBtn;

  Event.findByIdAndDelete(deletedItemId, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Successfully deleted");
      res.redirect("/admin");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Now it works perfectly and for the database, but most stuff I googled where showing to use

```
/*for the route */
app.delete(“delete/:id”), function() 

/*for the form */
<form method="POST" action="/delete/<%= event._id%>?_method=DELETE">
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

which I tried but got ran into some errors again and return to the original one which works, I don't really understand the whole app.post, app.delete because you also use the action /delete and then you can just remove it using mongoose, also I am not sure but for the form method in HTML it's said you only can use post and put, which confused me even more....